# Removing all strings from a list containing a mix of strings and numbers

Tags: python, list

I have a list which contains a mix of strings and numbers eg

```
old_list = [23, 35, string, 42, string]
```

I would like list to look like this

```
new_list = [23,35,45]
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: @Kasramvd: not quite, that filters on *strings **containing** numbers*.

Comment: Why users are answering a question that should be closed as "too broad"? This question doesn't meet the standards of Stack Overflow and I don't think we should encourage such questions.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I don't see how this is too broad, frankly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There are many ways to achieve that. Since we don't longer have the "lack of research efforts", I find it the most suitable.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: 'lack of research' is not off topic. It is perfectly valid for a question to be down voted for that reason, but that doesn't make it closeable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, but the solutions are the same. Although your answer is more comprehensive than the answers in suggested question, you could close the question and post your answer on  related question (or the duplicate which I'm sure has been asked already.) Anyway It's not a big deal, well done.

Comment: @Kasramvd: the vast majority of the solutions focus on testing for digits in strings.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I agree that this isn't too broad, but indirectly this is another "give me the codez" question. This shows lack of research effort, and I agree that it should be downvoted. But what do we do with "give me the codez" question? Close it. As per me, this should be the right action taken on this post.

Answer (score 6):

Use a list comprehension to filter on type:

```
new_list = [value for value in old_list if isinstance(value, int)]
```

This picks out *just* integers. If you need to support arbitrary numbers (floats, complex numbers, `decimal.Decimal` instances) use the [`numbers.Number` abstract type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html):

```
from numbers import Number

new_list = [value for value in old_list if isinstance(value, Number)]
```

You can also give `isintance()` a tuple of types to test against, if just need a a subset; for example:

```
new_list = [value for value in old_list if isinstance(value, (int, float))]
```

would filter on integers and floating point values.

Comment: Wouldn't  `[value for value in old_list if not isinstance(value, str)]` cover all bases?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: it would only cover the base where the other values are strings. If you have more types then no, it wouldn't cover *all* bases. :-)

Comment: @Martin, *I have a list which contains a mix of strings and numbers*.  I think the bases are well covered with `not isinstance(value, str)` ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I prefer filtering on what you want, not on what you don't want. Either category could expand over time, but I find that what you don't want can expand to a far greater set to have to filter on. I rather nail down the smaller set of what you *do* want.

Answer (score 2):

Apart form the already mentioned comprehension, you can consider the built-in filter function:

```
new_list = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), old_list)
```

Comment: List comprehension should be preferred however. It's more commonly used.

Comment: Note that in Python 3, [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) returns an iterator, not a list. Of course, in many situations an iterator may be superior to having a list, but if you _do_ want a list, eg, so you can index into it or count it, then you can do `list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), old_list))`.